# Keyboard key hold to run and release to pause the speech recognizer in python

Tags: python, keyboard, speech-recognition, keyboard-events

### I want hold key (eg. KeyA) to start and release key to pause

So basically when I hold KeyA I should be able to say "hello" and the speech_recognizer will run and as I release the KeyA it should pause the speech_recognizer but still able to speak the answer. speak() is text to speech

same like alexa on firestick tv remote we have to hold alexa button then speak and then release the button

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
def takeCommand():
# speech recognizer

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Hearing...")
    # r.pause_threshold = 1
    r.chunk_size = 2048
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.5)
    r.energy_threshold = 300
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Recognizing....")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    print(f"You said: {query}\n")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)  # to remove error from console remove this

    print("Say that again please...")
    return "None"
return query
pass

while True:

        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if 'hello' in query:
            speak("Hello, how are you?")
```

---